# Expand a volume residing on one X-RAID disk installed on a Netgear ReadyNas Duo v2

Tags: readynas

I've got a Netgear ReadyNas Duo v2 (2 disk slots). System is configured with X-RAID which does not provide flexibility but automatically expands based on a sort of RAID-5 logic.

I had 2 500 GB hard disk installed, redundant, so I had 500 GB of volume size.

I wanted to upgrade the whole system to 3 GB * 2 hard disk maintaining both the data already on the NAS and the data on one of the two 3 TB hard disks. So I did this:

1. Unplugged one disk from the ReadyNas. Now the readynas has 1*500 GB non redundant.
2. Plugged one empty 3 TB hard disk. Now the readynas has 1*500 GB + 1*3 TB, redundant. I waited for the resync.
3. I then unplugged the 500 GB hard disk, so that I have only the 3 TB hard disk with the previous data.

Now what I want is to copy the data on my other 3 TB hard disk in the NAS, so that I can plug this other disk in the NAS and use it for redundancy.

The problem is that: the NAS has the (single) 3 TB hard disk in X-RAID, but the volume does not expand to 3 TB, it remains fixed to 500 GB.

**Is there a way to tell the ReadyNas to force expanding the volume to the whole disk without plugging in another hard disk of the same size?**

Comment: [Please take a moment to read our FAQ.](http://serverfault.com/faq)  This question seems to me like it may be off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can add a larger disk, but the extra space will not be utilized until all disks are at least that size. When the init is complete, your data volume will begin to expand automatically. X-RAID supports replacing each of your disks with larger capacity disks while keeping your data intact, whether you have 2, 3, or 4 disks. Just reboot the ReadyNAS to start the volume expansion which occurs in the background. When the process completes, your data will remain intact, but your data volume capacity will have expanded to 3x of the smallest capacity disk in your ReadyNAS.

Source: http://www.readynas.com/?cat=54

**So to answer your question. It sounds like no.**